# Flutter: Pass data from a Future Class to Stateful Class

Tags: flutter, dart

Im trying to pass the String variable `Name` which is set in the 4th from bottom line of code (in my `Future getProduct()` Class), and display it as text in the body of my `testPage` Stateful class. It seems like such a simple thing to do however I have no clue to pass it. If anyone is able to help and kindly explain it would be much appreciated.

**my dart file:**

```
class testPage extends StatefulWidget {
  String barcodeResult;
testPage({required this.barcodeResult});

  @override
  _testPageState createState() => _testPageState(barcodeResult);
  
}

class _testPageState extends State<testPage> {
  String barcodeResult;
  _testPageState(this.barcodeResult);
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  getProduct();
  return Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.teal,
        title:Text('Found Your Item',
        style: TextStyle(
        fontFamily: 'Fredoka',
        fontSize: 25,
        ),
        ),
      ),
    body:Center(
      child:
        Text(Name,
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30),
        ),
    ),
  );
}

Future<Product?> getProduct() async {
    ProductQueryConfiguration configuration = ProductQueryConfiguration(
      barcodeResult,
      fields: [ProductField.NAME]);

  ProductResult result = await OpenFoodAPIClient.getProduct(configuration);

  if(result.status != 1) {
    print("Error retreiving the product : ${result.status}");;
    }

  String? Name = result.product!.productName;
   debugPrint("Test :${Name}");
}
}
```

Comment: You can use a Future Builder: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a Future and how do I use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63017280/what-is-a-future-and-how-do-i-use-it)

Comment: @Kantine Thank you both for your advice, Ive just tried using a future builder and still very much confused. Is there a way I could make the Name a global variable and access it through different classes that way?

Answer (score 1):

You can use like this

**ProductQueryConfiguration(widget.barcodeResult,fields:[ProductField.NAME]);**

```html
Future<Product?> getProduct() async {
    ProductQueryConfiguration configuration = ProductQueryConfiguration(
      widget.barcodeResult,
      fields: [ProductField.NAME]);

  ProductResult result = await OpenFoodAPIClient.getProduct(configuration);

  if(result.status != 1) {
    print("Error retreiving the product : ${result.status}");;
    }

  String? Name = result.product!.productName;
   debugPrint("Test :${Name}");
}
```

Happy to help you.

Comment: Thank you for your reply @JEMISH VASOYA, Sorry for the confusion Its the 'Name' String that I am looking to pass from `Future getProduct()` to `Class testPage` , not the barcodeResult

Comment: Please use this code i think help you...
https://dartpad.dev/?periwinkle-jungle-7881

Comment: Hi @JEMISH VASOYA The dartpad isn't loading for me, it is showing up as blank

Comment: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1AdxNwbS58vjlErfT7FzgDibBqD1As8mVd7Z9BluyxkE/edit?usp=sharing
pleace check this.

Comment: Thank you for your help @JEMISH VASOYA however its not what Im querying about